# Ресайз изображения в Django (cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO)

Tags: python, django

Необходимо сделать ресайз изображения в django. Дошел примерно до следующего решения. Не могу понять почему при вызове `Image.open(image_file)` вылетает

> cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x01F4DB70>

```
    image_field = self.cleaned_data.get('image')      
    image_file = BytesIO(image_field.read())
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    w, h = image.size
    image = image.resize((int(w/ 2) ,int(h / 2.0)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image_file = BytesIO()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не передавайте `image_file` в `BytesIO`. Передавайте сразу `Image.open(image_field)`
Суть в том что в поле image уже находиться file-like обьект который можно открыть через класс Pillow `Image.open()`

> After the field has been cleaned and validated, the UploadedFile
>   object will have an additional image attribute containing the Pillow
>   Image instance used to check if the file was a valid image.

Пример

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

if form.is_valid():
    image = Image.open(form.cleaned_data['file'])
    if image.mode != 'RGB':
        image = image.convert('RGB')
    crop_image = ImageOps.fit(image, (150, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```